# Temperature equalization

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I would like to ask you something about prevention of temperature equalization.
I  would really appreciate it if you can answer.

To begin with, I want to **store specific material(Thermoplastic elastomere to be exact) into a breathable microfiber bag and place it inside a safe**.
**This material is susceptible to heat and moisture.**

The safe has the following dimensions:
1.2 cubic feet,interior space measures 16.81 x 12.15 x 10.51 inches L x W x H.There are pre-drilled holes for bolting which I'm going to cover  in order to ''make'' the container airtight.

**My safe is stored in a house room, where temperature  does not exceed 86-96.2 F now in the summer.**

**Given TPE's susceptibility my intention is:
a)to keep lower temperature inside the bag than the rest of the room.
b)to decrease humidity inside the safe**

**For a)** 
I'm thinking of putting the microfiber bag inside a cooler bag that is insulated, in order to achieve lower temperature.However, I know that due to temperature equalization sooner or later it's going to be increased eventually.

I don't want to cool or freeze the TPE, just to protect it as much as possible from reaching room temperature.Ice packs or freeze boards might create moisture inside the cooler bag so I doubt that is an option.

**For b)**
I also thought of adding a mini defumidifier(the one I own works best in an airtight container,that's why I previously mentioned about covering safe's pre-drilled holes)  to ensure that moisture is controlled and it won't affect the TPE material.Nevertheless, a dehumidifier may increase temperature, especially now in the summer.Hence, instead of dehumidifier, I'm going to use silica gel packets inside the microfiber bag.

*I need to mention that I do have a  hygrometer/thermometer for measuring RH and temperature.*

Therefore my questions are:

**1)If I put ice packs/freeze boards outside of the cooler bag,but directly touching it(e.g.exactly above) can I achieve lower temperature or not?**

**2)Similar question to 1 but instead of putting icepacks/freeze boards above the cooler bag place them directly above my safe.**

**3)Do you have any recommendation for a) and b) issues after taking into account the description of my problem?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the temperature will equalize.  Ice will melt, heat will flow through insulators, etc., etc.

If you have access to the basement, you could put your safe in a corner, and wrap it with insulation (or put it in an insulating room).  This would tend to moderate the temperature changes and keep the temperature even with the surrounding ground (which will be cooler than the room air, unless you live someplace hot).

Otherwise you're stuck actively cooling the safe, with an air conditioner or refrigerator.

To keep your valuable stuff dry, put it into an airtight container with desiccant.  The desiccant will remove the water, the airtight container will keep moisture-laden air from getting in.  If you want it to stay dry forever, use a *really* airtight container.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Do you think the best insulator to wrapp my safe would be   a)common aluminum foil, b) a heat reflective reflector bubble Foil like this one https://www.amazon.co.uk/SuperFOIL-RadPack-Radiator-Insulation-Reflective/dp/B00GUDVUXW           c)car windscreen sunshades made specifically for heat protection/temperature reduction such as the following:https://www.amazon.co.uk/Car-Frost-Cover-Windshield-Windshields/dp/B077859VNR      https://www.amazon.co.uk/FREESOO-Windscreen-Windshield-Protector-Morning/dp/B015IHSWUY

Comment: Also, would silver aluminium foil adhesive Tape be enough for closing safe's predrilled holes,thus creating an airtght container?          

p.s.I don't know if the amazon links are allowed here.I  only added them in order to be more specific on the insulation I'm going to use.